# How to see activity on ActiveCollab v2.3.2

Tags: activecollab

I was recently asked to investigate an deleted project on active collab v2.3.2 but I can't find anything, I looked in the database and the "project id" assigned to the project is not listed in the database.

I'm not sure where else to look, I need to find when and who deleted the project?

Any ideas and help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello. ActiveCollab 2 did not have a soft delete option. Once project was moved to trash and permanently deleted, it was completely removed, including activities related to that project and its elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. That's bad, not been able to see who or what happened. Obviously added in the newer versions. Isn't there perhaps log files I can check to see what happened? Thanks.

Comment: Version 2 does not keep that type of log. Maybe if your server keeps log of all HTTP requests you can find a particular POST request that was sent to delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the help and input, I really do appreciated it. I will have a look and post my outcome here.